# How to change matMenuTriggerFor area of to be trigger only over the arrow

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

there.
I am trying to change the area, where the next menu panel will open.
Now, I am triggering the next menu panel, every time I hover over the title or the arrow, I would like to open this menu, only when I hover over the arrow.

Expectation:
To open the next panel on arrow hovering.

Actual result:
Open next panel, wherever over the button.

[image]

```
    <ng-container>
      <button mat-menu-item
              [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu.childMenu"
              (menuOpened)="getRelatedAttributes(option)"
              (click)="selectAttribute(option)"
      >
       {{option.title}}
      </button>
    </ng-container>
```

I tried moving the title out of the button and playing with flex, which works kinda , but I will lose all the nice styling that comes on hovering the button. Any ideas will be highly appreciated

Comment: on button hover are you able to open the menu ?

Comment: Yes, @ShivanshSeth. I am. But I want to open it at the last 25 of the are, like where the arrow is

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-nested-menu-yclrmd?embed=1&file=app/nested-menu-example.html

Here in the example solution provided for button hover, for hover event trigger on icon( arrow) call the event on icon.

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" 
            (mouseenter)="buttonEnter(levelOneTrigger)"
             (mouseleave)="buttonLeave(levelOneTrigger, button)">
         </i>

<button mat-menu-item
  [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu.childMenu"
  (menuOpened)="getRelatedAttributes(option)"
  (click)="selectAttribute(option)">
   <span >{{option.title}}
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" 
        (mouseenter)="buttonEnter(levelOneTrigger)"
         (mouseleave)="buttonLeave(levelOneTrigger, button)">
     </i>
   </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, but it still triggers open the menu on hover over the text. I want to find a solution on the arrow only. The [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu.childMenu" does that